# Can you tag multiple people in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

When replying to comments you can do `@username` to make sure they get a notification of your response.

But what should you do if you wanted to get the attention of to people? Would `@username @username2` do that, or should you make two different comments?

Comment: See the FAQ, section *Can I notify more than one person at a time?*

Comment: TL;DR: not possible in one comment, must do it with several comments, one for each user you want to ping.